# Eclipse RCP table disable some roows

Tags: eclipse, swt, row, rcp

I use Eclipse RCP tables, and I need to disable particular table rows, so they are shown grayed out and cannot be selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a selection listener to the table and, if the prohibited row is selected, deselect it (and possibly indicate why in a status bar message)?.

Comment: Thank you David. I think, your method is a bit too complicated. Besides, it will cause undesirable side effects (will fire all selection change listeners).